# Should we apply an historical lock to "Alternative to Facebook"?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

[Alternative to Facebook [closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1912/88163) (Deleted 2017-10-12) is a question asking for a web application recommendation, so it's now off-topic.

It has:

- 43 points, 46 upvotes, 3 downvotes.
- 23 answers
- 18 stars (marked as favorite)

From its stats panel:

> - asked 7 years, 5 months ago
> - viewed 1,836 times
> - active 3 months ago

Regarding the answers:

- The top answer has 30 points, 32 upvotes, 2 downvotes
- The accepted answer has 10 points, 12 upvotes, 2 downvotes. It's a link only answer.
- There are 6 answers (including the above) with 10 or more points.

It had a duplicate that was deleted few minutes ago ( 10K rep users and moderators have access to it: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6550/88163 )

Related

- [“Historic value” questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966/88163)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view count 1,836 is quite low for a 7-year old question. Most of those probably happened way back when the question was active.

Also, the fact that 10+ people liked some social network back in 2010 holds *very* little value in 2017. Those same people probably don't have the same opinion of that network now, if it even exists.

So, I don't see any reason for historical lock here. Nothing of value will be lost if this question gets deleted. And, given low viewcount, I don't see a pressing need to delete it, either. It's largely forgotten.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't need an historical lock.

Nor do I think we need to work to get it deleted. Vote on it and its answers as appropriate and leave it be.