# Old notable question closed as "Off topic" in December 2017

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31314/is-there-any-service-that-provides-accurate-driving-directions-to-a-location-at) I asked in 2012 has more than 282,000 views and it was still getting upvoted till early December:

> Is there any service that provides accurate driving directions to a location at a specified time of the day?

However now it has been closed as "off topic".

Is there any way to open it again? I understand that it is asking for a recommendation but it has been useful for a lot of people. This closure seems heavy handed.

Comment: I didn't study the answer too closely when I closed it based on it being a service recommendation.  I think the question can be rewritten to match to the given answer and remain open, honestly.

Comment: Closure != deletion. It merely means no more answers can be added. The question and its answer(s) can still receive votes.

Comment: @ale There are currently two votes for deletion on it, which I don't think is merited in this case.  I think it is an excellent answer and so should be preserved from deletion.  Editing the question to match the answer would lose some of the SEO stature, but it would render any notion of being deleted moot, and even merit reopening.

Comment: @jonsca: And it's questions like these I've been voting to undelete. It's good content, just no longer on-topic.

Comment: squashbuff: As jonsca mentions, if you were to edit the question to be asking specifically how to do what you want with Google Maps (which would match the answer) the question would once again be on-topic, and this whole issue would be moot.

Comment: @ale and jonsca , Thank you. I have edited the question. Hopefully it won't be considered off-topic anymore.

Answer (score 5):

It should not be re-opened as nowadays it's an off-topic question, actually it already has 2 delete votes. If it receive one more, it will be deleted.

IMHO the best way to proceed is to post a similar question on [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Related Meta Q&A

- [Should we apply an historical lock to "Alternative to Facebook"?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4474/88163)

Related Help Articles

- [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)