# Why do we have the [webapp-rec] tag when it is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-clean-up

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec

The tag description reads

> Web app recommendations are OFF-TOPIC on Web Applications Stack Exchange, but might be on-topic for Software Recommendations Stack Exchange if they're sufficiently scoped.

If web apps recommendation are off-topic, why do we have that tag?

Answer (score 3):

There are several sites on the SE network that have tags that state "*Do not use*" in some form or another.

This is intended to indicate to a (first-time) poster that a question in this subject is likely to be poorly received - or worse.  It is simpler to put these tags into the system than to go through the process of getting the tag formally blacklisted.

This technique doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

[webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) was created during the public beta (more precisely in July 2010) before web app recommendations were removed from the site scope in January 2014.

Many of the questions having this tag don't have another tag. It will not make sense to create one to be applied to closed questions just to remove it. By the other hand it serves as "honey pot" to catch questions from people that blatantly ignore the site scope and workings that decide to ask for a webapp recommendation.

## Related

### From Public Beta

- [Should mods start making webapp-rec questions as CW?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/521/88163)
- [Old notable question closed as "Off topic" in December 2017](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4493/88163)

### Before become off-topic

- [Make all recommendation questions out of scope and off topic, regardless of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/88163)

### After become off-topic

- [When should I vote to delete a question on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/88163)
- [Should we delete questions posted during the private beta?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4941/88163)